# HTML5 Video color difference Chrome & Internet Explorer

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, video, rendering

I'm using the HTML5 video tag to play a short video on my website with this code:

```
<video width="100%" poster="/images/video_preview.jpg">
    <source src="/images/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/images/movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The video's are shown but when I'm on my website in Google Chrome the colors look a little bit more purple then they should be and on Internet Explorer the whole video got a darker look. I also have a preview image as you can see in my code and that image is now a different color then shown on the browser and that's not what I want. I noticed that for example Apple also uses the `<video>` tag but they have no color difference between browsers.

How is this possible? I'm using the same code for all browsers. Is this because of the rendering of all the browsers?

How can I fix this? Thanks.

---

**ADDED BOUNTY**

Is there anyone that had the same issue with video rendering in browsers and can help me fix this issue? Still haven't figured out why the same video file is shown darker in Internet Explorer and with a purple glow in Google Chrome.

The page is online so you can see the difference [here](http://www.carvingfitness.com/movement/).

Comment: I tested your video and it's working fine ! I don't see any problem ! Could you provide some images of the problem on IE and Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try to render mp4 video with "601" colorscope. This should help.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I wouldn't even bother with the other solutions here.
Download Handbrake, it's a free and opensource encoding program. Import the video, and switch to the 'video' tab. Click the Colourspace dropdown, and choose one of the 601 options. There's 2. One for American preference, and one for Europe.

I'm UK based, so I chose the EU version, hit 'encode' and 45 seconds later my video was sorted. I then re-uploaded to my site and tested in Chrome, works perfectly, even today in 2024.

Answer (score 0):

> How is this possible?

**About the video**

Do not expect 100% the exact same behavior from browsers, especially not colors and video. Display inconsistency is expected between different browsers (and especially different systems).

Different browsers might use different software implementations of h264 decoder, different video enhancement plugins, etc.

This is not a problem with your source or anything you can forcefully fix.

**The preview image**

This is something you might be able to fix. [The image is maybe saved in a certain color profile which isn't supported by both browsers or they simply render differently.](http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/)
When saving an image the safest way is to always select "save for web & devices", which is a sRGB profile. [Check your photoshop or image editor settings if needed.](http://usabilitypost.com/2008/07/30/photoshop-color-profiles-for-web-images/)

Comment: I know I can't expect the browsers to have 100% the same behavior but I'm wondering how other people manage to get it working. The difference between IE & Chrome is really big.

Comment: Have you checked on different systems? Because this problem might be only on your PC. Like i said it's not a problem with your source video.  Maybe try disabling hardware acceleration on both browsers, firefox and chrome and safari have separated settings for these.

Comment: Yeah I checked on iOS (works good, no problem), OS X has same problems as on a Windows.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with a video. 3 Browser (FF Chrome and Edge), 3 different Monitors...everywhere different colors, they were lighter or darker than expected. As we have a colored background it stands out, that the video background is different from the browser color, although video and browser use the same color code. We finally extended the video the whole browser width.

Answer (score 0):

Different browser will have different implementation of certain things. Especially IE. However, I have never heard of this happening. If you have CSS code or any JavaScript code effecting the video element can cause this. It must be with the way the browsers differing ways of rendering the image.
You can try to reimplement the poster function through JavaScript. Have it draw and image. When that image is clicked have it remove the image and draw the video in its place.

Comment: The preview image is just fine. The color/tint of the video is really different in IE and Chrome. That's the main problem, you can see for yourself on [this website](http://www.carvingfitness.com/movement/).

Comment: That is why I suggested doing that to see if it where to help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, it's to do with how the browser renders the video on its video panel - something that's difficult to change. You could try re-encoding the video and altering the colours that way to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Safari = no proper webM support. Safari quite popular I hear. Have to use giant gifs... ‍♀️‍♀️

Came across this issue several times, very annoying, no proper solution, so I ended up using transparent background video!

.webm video format allows transparency (way smaller and higher res than .gif or .apng) https://web.dev/replace-gifs-with-videos/

If you have a transparent .mov, you can convert it to .webm using ffmpeg (Handbrake seems to remove the alpha channel)

Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video-in.mov -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p -auto-alt-ref 0 video-out.webm
```

^ webm video currently not playing in safari, "Safari only supports VP8 used in WebRTC." https://caniuse.com/webm,
https://webkit.org/blog/8672/on-the-road-to-webrtc-1-0-including-vp8/. No idea what that means in practice, any help in comments appreciated

ffmpeg command src: https://superuser.com/a/624564/787069

Answer (score -1):

i ran into a similar issue with Google Chrome and youtube videos.  In Chrome my video had a yellow tint to it while in Firefox the video was fine.  I managed to remove the color distortions in Chrome by doing the following:

1. In Chrome's url bar, enter "chrome://flags"
2. enable the "Override software rendering list" flag

This obviously won't affect how other viewers see your videos, but at least you get to see it correctly...