# ffmpeg libx264 settings to keep exact colors

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

does anyone have an idea how I need to edit these ffmpeg settings to keep the original colors? I'm trying to convert a video, but need to absolutely keep the rgb colors, as it's going to be embedded into a website with a background color.

The parameters look currently like this:

```
'-acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 160k  '
'-vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 25 '
'-maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -vb 1200k -f mp4 '
'-threads 0'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on input color properties.

Comment: @Mulvya How do you mean? I'm rendering h264 from after effects

Comment: You shouldn't get a huge difference, then. Note that video for web doesn't store colors as RGB, so there will be some change (~1%) due to the conversion to YCbCr. What you could do is take a screenshot of the page as a JPG. Load it in AE and set your comp bg to that color using a color picker.

Comment: @Mulvya I think I found the solution. I can't control the rendering of the browser, so I will get the color of the first pixel and then change the background color accordingly. Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44523649/1779355