# Altering background color to match video changes by browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I would like the background of a video to match the background of its container. However, setting the container background manually has different results in different browsers (apparently due to localized hardware acceleration settings).

The solution is to read the color of the pixels in the video and update the background accordingly-- originally found here ---> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44523649/4072697

However, this method (including the one presented in the comment for it) produce the same result (different colors in different browsers)

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8hw1mq5/1/) will not run the video due to cross origin errors, but includes the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <video class="videos" id="test" controls="none" autoplay="" loop name="media"><source src="https://r4---sn-ab5szne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1574210358&amp;ei=1jbUXaubDo_t8gTuhJzwDw&amp;ip=24.103.48.189&amp;id=o-AMlyNgFeuPfxNCz0P6eVhp14foi9XPmWLqDxWO5zEwYA&amp;itag=22&amp;source=youtube&amp;requiressl=yes&amp;mm=31,26&amp;mn=sn-ab5szne7,sn-vgqsknll&amp;ms=au,onr&amp;mv=m&amp;mvi=3&amp;pl=18&amp;initcwndbps=1726250&amp;mime=video/mp4&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;dur=5.363&amp;lmt=1471775895725173&amp;mt=1574188655&amp;fvip=4&amp;fexp=23842630&amp;c=WEB&amp;sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,mime,ratebypass,dur,lmt&amp;sig=ALgxI2wwRQIgJuAGaoYOYn6-XQ9ylB8uNwW2rKt09Q2zkixlP-5r4-ACIQCqMpK0BRTwnTzErcNFADAKc7k0YQPjBxJJAQD2vSRR7w==&amp;lsparams=mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl,initcwndbps&amp;lsig=AHylml4wRgIhAOYG1-AAZcBkmaJJI502ztNGkv_9dUhOPNd8kZpJCYLRAiEA9BeuIqWpXG5JMtTFTgDCtmEsoaz0A7zOl6Lku3bj6bQ=" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

JS:

```
      //allow crossOrigin
     var testVid = document.getElementById('test')
     testVid.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

function drawingLoop() {
      requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(drawingLoop)
      ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, vidWidth, vidHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  function setVideoBgColor(vid, backgroundElement) {

      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      //size of canvas space to copy pixel onto
      canvas.width = 10;
      canvas.height = 10;

      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 10, 10);

      var p = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 10, 10).data;

      var colorBoost = 0;
      var colorR = p[0]+colorBoost;
      var colorG = p[1]+colorBoost;
      var colorB = p[1]+colorBoost;
      //colorLayer.data[pixelPos];
      backgroundElement.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + colorR+ "," + colorG + "," + colorB + ")";
  }
   document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("play",function(){
        setVideoBgColor(document.getElementById('test'),this.parentElement);
    })
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#test{
  margin-top:20%;
  margin-left:15%;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? There seems to be a browser-bug which causes color shifts when gpu acceleration is enabled.